# Why there are a lot of log with the ip address of the server in litespeed?

Tags: linux, web-server, logging, litespeed

I have a server with Litespeed web server. When I check the access logs of a domain there are a lot of lines like the following:

```
188.165.x.x - - [04/Feb/2017:10:16:16 +0330] "GET /assets/source/images/vector-images14/thumbs/327_90_auto.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 2639 "-" "-"<br>
```

in which 188.165.x.x is the ip address of my server! This causes the log files get big and consequently the root partition gets full and the server goes out of service. I want to know why requests with the IP address of the server are logged? I think the IP address of the clients who visit the web site should only be stored in access log files!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It depends on your config, likely are either your log settings (you might be logging a wrong field) or you maybe "reverse proxy"-ing something

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about what you are logging, you will have to look into the config files and relevant documentation for litespeed and your web app. I can though help you with you log file size issue.

All you should need to to is add a suitable configuration file for logrotate to /etc/logrotate.d. The [logrotate(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) utility is the standard method for controlling log files on Linux based systems.